# PHP Registrar líneas checked

Tags: php, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Formulario en modo lista que registra únicamente las filas que están marcadas con el check. El formulario tiene dos campos, CODE y COST. Los he creado como name[] y COST[] que irían al fichero post. Ahí es donde con un for que recorre todos los registros, inserta únicamente los que tienen el check marcado. Aparte, en el fichero check.php debería  actualizar el contador porque ahora lo tengo a 5.Las dudas que tengo son: no sé si el array está bien montado y creo que debería poner un contador dentro del while para que en el for del fichero check.php recorra esa cantidad de registros. Gracias.*

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="check.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>CODE</th>
                    <th>COST</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row["CODE"];?>">
                        <?php echo $row["CODE"];?>            
                        <input type="hidden" name="COST[]" value="<?php echo $row["COST"];?>">       
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $row["COST"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="save" id="submit">
        </form>
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
//El código del fichero check.php es este:
<?php
    $database = "ddbb";
    $serverName = "server";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"ddbb", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    
    $counter = 5;   
    for($x=0; $x<=$counter; $x++){
    if(!empty($_POST['name'][$x])){                     
    $CODE = $_POST['CODE'][$x];
    $COST = $_POST['COST'][$x];
    $sql="INSERT INTO COST (CODE,COST) VALUES('$CODE','$COST')";
    sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No tengo idea a que te refieres con que si el array está bien montado. Lo del contador sobra, usa un `foreach` https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp

Comment: Buenas. En relación al array en el formulario de registro he creado uno para cada variable. Uno para el check, otro para code y otro para cost. No sé si eso está bien. Y si la recepción en el fichero check.php es correcta.

Comment: Creo que el array de `cost` sobra, por ese campo no lo necesitas. El `check` obviamente debe estar y el `code` lo necesitas en el value para identificar el checkbox. En el fichero `check.php` necesitas usar un `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé por qué te complicas tanto la vida en este código. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué limitarlo a `5`? ¿y si en vez de `5` chequea `2` o chequea `8`? Se supone que el código debería ser funcional para cualquier caso, sin importar el número.

Por otra parte, no es necesario un contador, asumiendo que por cada `code` habrá un `cost`, puedes usar un `foreach` obteniendo el índice y usar el índice para obtener el valor del cost en ese índice.

Otro problema, se nota una confusión aquí:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'][$x])){
```

Y aquí:

```
$CODE = $_POST['CODE'][$x];
```

Realmente, en el `form` no hay nada con `name="CODE[]"`, supongo que el input al que le diste un `name="name[]"` es el que debería llevar `name="CODE[]"`.

Aplicando las siguientes correcciones y mejoras debería funcionar:

#### En el formulario

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="CODE[]" value="<?php echo $row["CODE"];?>">
                    <?php echo $row["CODE"];?>            
                    <input type="hidden" name="COST[]" value="<?php echo $row["COST"];?>">       
                </td>
                <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $row["COST"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

#### En `check.php`

```
<?php
    $database = "ddbb";
    $serverName = "server";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"ddbb", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    /*
       Usamos fusión de null para saber si hay valores posteados
    */
    $codes=$_POST['CODE'] ?? null;
    $costs=$_POST['COST'] ?? null;

    if ($codes && $costs) 
    {
    
        /*
            Asumiendo que por cada code hay un cost asociado
            recorremos el array de $codes obteniendo los índices
            y usamos esos índices para obtener su valor
            correspondiente en $costs
        */
        foreach ($codes as $k=>$code)
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO COST (CODE,COST) VALUES('$code','$costs[$k]')";
            sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
?>
```

Cabe decir que este código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías implementar **consultas preparadas** para evitar ese gravísimo riesgo de seguridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he conseguido resolverlo aplicando los cambios indicados. En el formulario he actualizado el input quedando de la siguiente manera: <input type="checkbox" name="CODE[]" value="<?php echo $row["CODE"];?>">. La siguiente modificación fue en el post, añadir ese código. Muchas gracias.